# Использование одного класса в другом

Tags: классы, c++

Здравствуйте,
у менят есть класс "А" и есть класс "В".

Проблема: Класса "А" работает с comPORT объявить я классе "В" я могу его только 1 раз.

Вопрос: Как в методах класса "В" мне использовать методы из класса "А" для остылки информации?

Comment: Какой-то бессвязный набор слов. Попробуйте переформулировать ваш вопрос, что ли.

Comment: @foxmen, небольшой пример Вашего кода (классы A, B и их создание в программе) не помешает.

Comment: @foxmen, Перефразируйте, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос: исправьте грамматические ошибки, правильно расставьте запятые. Если ещё добавите побольше уточняющей информации, то Вы ускорите получение ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Pettern Registry как вариант.

Comment: или я ничего не понял вообще. this

Comment: @Eugene Smiths, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно вас понимаю, вам пригодится *forward declaration* и указатели на экземпляры нужных классов

```
// header_a.h
class B;

class A
{
    B *bObj_;
    //...
};

// header_b.h
class A;

class B
{
    A *aObj_;
    //...
};
```